# Boost merge containers

Tags: c++, boost, boost-container

Boost does not give a merge method to merge set or multiset.

So I need to do something like this to merge.

```cpp
int main() {
    boost::container::flat_multiset<int> set1 = {1, 2, 3};
    boost::container::flat_multiset<int> set2 = {3, 4, 5};

    // Manually insert elements from set2 into set1
    for (const auto& value : set2) {
        set1.insert(value);
    }
}
```

Is it efficient?
How to deal with multiple sets ?

Comment: You mean `set1.insert(boost::container::ordered_range, set2.begin(), set2.end());`?

Comment: Technically, `std::merge`  does exist as it was moved to C++ long time ago

Comment: @康桓瑋, yes but it's not handy when dealing with many sets

Comment: @TedZach why? The `ordered_range` insertion is likely (much) more efficient.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie posted an answer to show why `std::merge` is *not* the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I went ahead and checked my prediction:

> @TedZach why? The ordered_range insertion is likely (much) more efficient. –
> sehe
> 1 hour ago

Indeed, merging 100 random flat multisets of 10'000 elements is **MUCH** faster using the specialized order insertion than the naive approach. Doing it correctly [with `std::merge`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) is very clumsy because you cannot insert directly into the destination anyways:

> The behavior is undefined if the destination range overlaps either of
> the input ranges (the input ranges may overlap each other).

So no, you most definitely don't want `std::merge`.

You **CAN** do a lot of work and manually inplace-merge into a fixed sequence to then adopt into a multiset, but that's not worth the effort, and merely does the same as the ordered insertion anyways. This becomes even more felt if you need to support unique as well as multi-sets, or sets with custom order predicates.

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ed4a33c2e5f2979)**

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/container/flat_set.hpp>
#include <boost/container_hash/hash.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
namespace bc = boost::container;
using set_t  = bc::flat_multiset<int>;
using data_t = std::vector<set_t>;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

namespace /*file static*/ {
    auto generate_sets(unsigned num_sets, unsigned set_size = 10'000) {
        data_t sets(num_sets);

        std::mt19937 prng{std::random_device{}()};
        auto         gen = bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<int>{-9'999, +9'999}, prng);

        for (auto& set : sets)
            generate_n(inserter(set, set.end()), set_size, gen);

        return sets;
    }

    // the naive approach
    set_t naive_merge(data_t const& sets) {
        set_t r;
        for (auto const& s : sets)
            r.insert(s.begin(), s.end());
        return r;
    }

    // std::merge really doesn't fit the bill here:
    set_t std_merge(data_t const& sets) {
        if (sets.empty())
            return {};
        set_t r(sets.front()), tmp;
        for (auto const& s : sets | std::views::drop(1)) {
            tmp.clear();
            std::merge(r.begin(), r.end(), s.begin(), s.end(), inserter(tmp, tmp.end()));
            r.swap(tmp);
        }
        return r;
    }

    // the correct usage of ordered flatmultiset::insert!
    set_t fast_merge(data_t const& sets) {
        set_t r;
        for (auto const& s : sets)
            r.insert(bc::ordered_range, s.begin(), s.end());
        return r;
    }

    // this is the manual to do similar to fast_merge:
    set_t manual_inplace(data_t const& sets) {
        set_t::sequence_type underlying;
        // preallocate
        underlying.reserve( //
            accumulate(sets.begin(), sets.end(), size_t{},
                       [](size_t acc, set_t const& s) { return acc + s.size(); }));

        // using repeated inplace_merge:
        for (auto const& s : sets) {
            underlying.reserve(underlying.size() + s.size()); // avoid iterator invalidation

            auto m = underlying.end();
            underlying.insert(m, s.begin(), s.end());
            std::inplace_merge(underlying.begin(), m, underlying.end());
        }

        // adopt the sequence!
        return {bc::ordered_range, underlying.begin(), underlying.end()};
    }

} // namespace

int main() {
    auto bench = [sets = generate_sets(100, 10'000)](auto caption, set_t (*f)(data_t const&)) {
        static auto constexpr now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;

        auto start = now();
        auto r     = f(sets);
        auto stop  = now();

        size_t checksum = boost::hash_range(begin(r), end(r));
        std::cout << caption << "\t" << (stop - start) / 1.ms << "ms\t" //
                  << std::hex << checksum << std::dec << "\n";
        return r;
    };

    // benchmark
    bench("naive_merge",    naive_merge);
    bench("std_merge",      std_merge);
    bench("fast_merge",     fast_merge);
    bench("manual_inplace", manual_inplace);
}
```

Printing

```
naive_merge 96.4958ms   e81a4707eb9e51c6
std_merge   573.727ms   e81a4707eb9e51c6
fast_merge  67.776ms    e81a4707eb9e51c6
manual_inplace  78.4506ms   e81a4707eb9e51c6
```

Or locally:

[image]

---